# Is it good idea to use Optional.orElseGet to do some logging logic

Tags: java

I want to use Optional for handling null values, the "tricky" part which I cannot think of what is the best way to do - is that I want to do logging if value is null. I can achieve that with following code - but it feels awkward.

**(Update: I have posted my own answer, with Optional from Java 9)**

Lets say code looks like this:

```
// logLine.getSomeProperty returns Optional<String>

List<LogDetails> logDetails = logLine.getSomeProperty()
    .map(this::extractLogDetails)
    .orElseGet(() -> logError(logLine));
```

```
List<LogDetails> extractLogDetails(String s) {
    List<LogDetails> logDetails = new ArrayList<>();
    String sp = "(?:([A-Z0-9]{5,7})-([A-Z0-9]{9})-(.{4}))"; 
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(sp, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
        logDetails.add(new LogDetails(m.group(1), m.group(2), m.group(3)));
    }
    return logDetails;
}
```

```
List<LogDetails> logError(LogLine logLine) {
    log.error("Error while ... {} ", logLine));
    persistence.setErrorStatus(logLine, FAILED_PARSING);
    return new ArrayList<>();
}
```

It would do what I want, but I have several "problems" with it.

- I found it odd, that method called `orElseGet` is used for logging
  errors.
- I could replace orElseGet with orElseThrow and logError there and DO NOT throw anything - which I don't like either.
- logError method returns List which I don't use and it looks weird to return something from method which should be void.
- Simply there must be better way
- Cases where someProperty is not null, but there are no matches - I would like to log as well, but for that I would need another line of code to check if `logDetails.size() == 0`

Comment: It *should* feel awkward, since it is an exceptionally bad idea to change the result type to some dummy value just so you can use `orElseGet()`. What are you going to do the next time you want to log when null, but the object type is different? --- *"Simply there must be better way"* Yes, don't misuse `Optional` for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `orElseGet` is not really intended as an error handling mechanism, but as a way to generate a different default value in case the `Optional` instance is not carrying any.

If you want to check if the `Optional` is empty explicitly, simply use the `Optional.isPresent()` check, and do the `logError()` in that case.

What you need to think first is, if the `Optional` is empty, what do you want to do? Apart from logging the error, do you want to proceed with an empty list?

If yes then you could have something like this:

```
List<LogDetails> logDetails = logLine.getSomeProperty()
    .map(this::extractLogDetails)
    .orElseGet(Collections::emptyList);
```

After which you could do:

```
if (logDetails.isEmpty()) {
  logError(logline);
}
```

Alternatively, if you do not want to have an empty list at all, you could keep things at optional level. This way, both cases where the `getSomeProperty()` is empty or when the generated list is empty are handled in the same way.

```
Optional<List<LogDetails>> logDetailsOpt = logLine.getSomeProperty() 
                       .map(this::extractLogDetails)
                       .filter(list -> !list.isEmpty());

if (!logDetailsOpt.isPresent()) {
  logError(logLine);
}
```

In both cases, `logError()` is not expected to return anything. It is doing what it is intended to do in its name, logging the error.

Rather than trying to overuse the functionality of `Optional`, try to make your intentions in your code clear. There is more value in readability.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than changing result type or logging inside stream you can simply return partitioned Map. Then after obtaining the result, execute log function on the resulting map accordingly.

```
 Map<Boolean, List<String>> map = Stream.of("a", "aaa", "aaaa")
           ----
                .collect(() -> Collectors.partitioningBy(predicate))
           ----
```

Comment: Thanks, thats also an interesting approach.

Answer (score 2):

While I am grateful for the answers, but I just recently find out, that Java 9 introduced new method to Optional and I like it best.
Here is example.

```
Optional.ofNullable(user).ifPresentOrElse( u -> logger.info("User is:" + u.getEmail()),
  () -> logger.info("User not found"));
```

Comment: `.ifPresentOrElse` returns `void`, so it doesn't feel like you will be able to use it in a stream, would you ?